# Laravel how can i store child with parent if the parent data doesnt exist in restful api

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, shopping-cart

so i want to create a card product feature in my laravel api, i create a table where products belongs to cartsdetail and carts has many cartsdetail, i make a function store in cartdetail controller that i want to store some cartdetail in 1 carts ,but i have problem in cartdetail controller when I store data in postman , there is also an addition to the carts id. i want it to be like if data carts(carts_id) doesnt exist->store request->carts_id, if exist return store cartsdetails.
the ERD looks like this
[image: the ERD looks like this]

my cartdetail controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
 $this->validate($request, [
            'carts_id' => 'required',
            'products_id' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required'
  ]);
        $useritem = $request->user();
        $productitem = Products::findOrFail($request->products_id);
        $cart = Cart::where('users_id', $useritem->id)->where('status', 'carts')->first();

        if ($cart) {
            $itemcart = $cart;
        }else{
            $no_invoice = Cart::where('users_id', $useritem->id)->count();
            $inputancart['id'] = $request->carts_id;
            $inputancart['users_id']= $useritem->id;
            $inputancart['no_resi'] = Str::random(10).' ' .str_pad(($no_invoice + 1), '3', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $inputancart['status'] = 'cart';
            $itemcart = Cart::create($inputancart);
        }
        $cekdetail = CartDetails::where('carts_id', $itemcart->id)->where('products_id', $productitem->id)->first();
        $quantity = $request->quantity;
        $price = $productitem->price;
        $discount = $productitem->discount != null ? $productitem->discount->discount_nominal: 0;
        $subtotal = ($quantity * $price) - $discount;

        if ($cekdetail){
            $cekdetail->updatedetail($cekdetail, $quantity, $price, $discount);
            $cekdetail->carts->updatetotal($cekdetail, $quantity, $price, $discount);
        } else {
            $inputan = $request->all();
            $inputan['carts_id'] = $request->carts_id;
            $inputan['products_id'] = $productitem->id;
            $inputan['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $inputan['price'] = $price;
            $inputan['discount'] = $discount;
            $inputan['subtotal'] = ($price * $quantity) - $discount;
            $itemdetail = CartDetails::create($inputan);
            $itemdetail->carts->updatetotal($itemdetail->carts, $subtotal);
        }
        return response()->json(['Product successfully added to cart']);
    }


//model cartdetail
public function updatedetail($itemdetail, $quantity, $price, $voucher){
    $this->attributes['quantity'] = $itemdetail->quantity + $quantity;
    $this->attributs['subtotal'] = $itemdetail->subtotal + ($quantity * ($price - $voucher));
    self::save();
}
public function updatetotal($itemcart, $subtotal){
    $this->attributes['subtotal']= $itemcart->subtotal + $subtotal;
    $this->attributes['total']= $itemcart->total +$subtotal;
    self::save();
}

//index cart controller
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $itemuser = $request->user();
    $itemcart = Cart::where('users_id', $itemuser->id)->where('status', 'cart')->with('cartdetails')->get();
    return response()->json(['data' => 'Shopping cart', 'itemcart'=> $itemcart], 300);
}
```

I think the problem is only here
[image: I think the problem is only here]

(edit) this is not error visible, but it duplicate my parent data(carts), first store is not problem but the second time to more that duplicate my parent data like this

```
first store was :   
"itemcart": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "users_id": 3,
            "no_resi": "oxIkpZ3xhl 001",
            "discount": 0,
            "subtotal": 300000,
            "status": "cart",
            "total": 300000,
            "created_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z",
            "cartdetails": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "products_id": 2,
                    "carts_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "discount": 0,
                    "price": 100000,
                    "subtotal": 300000,
                    "created_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }

and then to this :
 "data": "Shopping cart",
    "itemcart": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "users_id": 3,
            "no_resi": "oxIkpZ3xhl 001",
            "discount": 0,
            "subtotal": 599091,
            "status": "cart",
            "total": 599091,
            "created_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-08T06:29:22.000000Z",
            "cartdetails": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "products_id": 2,
                    "carts_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "discount": 0,
                    "price": 100000,
                    "subtotal": 300000,
                    "created_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-04-08T06:25:06.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "products_id": 4,
                    "carts_id": 1,
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "discount": 0,
                    "price": 99697,
                    "subtotal": 299091,
                    "created_at": "2022-04-08T06:29:22.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-04-08T06:29:22.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "users_id": 3,
            "no_resi": "Nf0BkdaxTk 002",
            "discount": 0,
            "subtotal": 0,
            "status": "cart",
            "total": 0,
            "created_at": "2022-04-08T06:29:22.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-08T06:29:22.000000Z",
            "cartdetails": []
        }
    ]
```

with the same value store but the parent become duplicate

big thanks! for anyone can solve my problem.

Comment: please mention the error you phase

Comment: it is already edited below my code, thanks